# Using Cross Domain Webpage on my Website

Tags: html, iframe, x-frame-options

I am making a webpage on my website url of the page is as below.

http://www.hitechcaddservices.com/mechanical/design/engineering-design-automation/configure-your-product/

I am making an iFrame to display "https://configurator360.autodesk.com/743594009607818941/l1x6g1bxtfmg" on the webpage, this URL is created by my company to show product configuration to our clients.

I am not getting content on my website page due to X-Frame-Option issue (cross browser iFrame is not allowed). How i can make this iFrame working or is there any alternate way to display above given URL same way on my webpage.

Regards
Manoj Soni

Comment: you can enable cross browser using chrome extension.

Comment: what server side language are you using ? php c# ... ?

Comment: you could enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or suck the `autodesk.com` page on server side and displaying it in your master page without frames

Comment: I am doing this using Wordpress so it should be "PHP"

Comment: I tried following in my .htaccess but not working.  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>